# How to add new class without reseting previous ones in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add underline to menu item when its active. All works fine, but when I click on an item, its previous classes received from the ReactTransitionGroup add-on component are reset. For example when I click second item the classes will be reset and only active will remain. I want the active class to be insert to existing without cleaning the previous ones.

The .active has ::after pseudo-class

### [image]

```
const NavItems = (props) => {
  const items = ["section1", "section2", "section3", "section4", "section5"];
  const [activeItem, setActive] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
     <NavItemsOverlay open={props.open} />

     <ScollLinks open={props.open}>
       {items.map((item, index) => {
         return (
          <CSSTransition
            in={props.open}
            key={index}
          timeout={{enter: 100 * index, exit: 0 }}
          classNames="fade ">
            <Link
              className={activeItem === index ? " active" : ""}
              onClick={() => setActive(index)} >
              {item}
            </Link>
          </CSSTransition>
      );
     })}
    </ScollLinks>
   </>
   );
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be running into [issue #318](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/issues/318), which is still open. The person posting the issue thinks it's a bug, and the [`CSSTransition` documentation](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) does say:

> A few details to note about how these classes are applied:
>
> 1. They are *joined* with the ones that are already defined on the child component, so if you want to add some base styles, you can use `className` without worrying that it will be overridden.

...so yeah, that sounds like a bug.

The best way to solve it would be to fork the project, fix the bug, and send a PR. :-)

A really hacky way to work around it would be to use a `data-*` attribute instead of a class:

```
<Link
  data-cls={activeItem === index ? " active" : ""}
  onClick={() => setActive(index)} >
  {item}
</Link>
```

And then in the CSS, instead of:

```
.active::after {
    /* ... */
}
```

You'd have

```
[data-cls~=active]::after {
    /* ... */
}
```

That uses [class-like attribute matching](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-representation) to match that element.